# OpenVPN via Network Manager not working

Tags: networking, network-manager, openvpn

I have set up an OpenVPN server to which I can succesfully connect from Android and iOS devices.

I am having troubling setting up my Ubuntu 18.04 machine as a client. I installed the gnome OpenVPN client so I could connect via the Network Manager. Having done so with the openvpn file and password provided by the server, I get the message that I succesfully connected to the VPN server.

However, I cannot actually reach the VPN network; in fact, I do not even get a response when I ping the VPN server on my client machine.

What could be causing this? There is no firewall enabled on the client side.

Edit: just tried connecting with

```
sudo openvpn --config [ovpn file name]
```

instead. Worked flawlessly. So the problem is with the network manager. Does it somehow not import the right settings from the *.ovpn file?

Edit 2 on request: When connected to VPN through CLI command: I can ping 8.8.8.8 and any machine on the local network. When supposedly "connected" to the VPN through network manager GUI I can ping neither 8.8.8.8, nor any machine on the local network, nor the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

You said you can connect i.e. from a phone. Well it says connected...ok. Does the VPN Server side knows what to do with your traffic?
Same goes for your Linux machine.
Its connected meaning you got authenticated. Does the server knows what to do with your network traffic?

Here's an example...

`000 #1287: "ciscoxxxxx" STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 1845s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner
000 #1287: "ciscoxxxxx" esp.yyyyy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (0 bytes) esp.yyyyy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (0 bytes); tunnel
000 #1286: "ciscoxxxx2" STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 1503s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner
000 #1286: "ciscoxxxx2" esp.yyyyy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (3496 bytes, 35s ago) esp.cyyyyd@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (0 bytes); tunnel
000 #1281: "ciscoxxxx2" STATE_MAIN_I4 (ISAKMP SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 78757s; newest ISAKMP`
From the above we can see my VPN Server has established connections.

`root#iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  x.x.x.x(an ip here)  xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24      policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 16392 proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx       policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 16392 proto esp
the above is rules to my VPN Server tell him what to do with the traffic received from which source and where to route it.
so ...on and on and on depending on your rules/needs.

ofc its not the same software maybe but the set up its pretty much the same

Comment: Although I must admit your answer was too technical for my limited knowledge, I do think the problem is not on the server side. As I added to the question, connecting through the CLI works perfectly, the problem is with the network manager.

Comment: try this then. While connected to the VPN try to traceroute an internet IP. (example 8.8.8.8) google dns. Post the resaults.

Comment: Pinging works when connected through the CLI tool, but not when connected through the network manager. In the latter case, I cannot even ping the server.

Comment: follow these steps please. 
1.Connect to VPN
2. Open terminal
3. Ping www.google.com
4. ping 8.8.8.8
5. ping your gateway and a local IP of your network (not localhost)
6. post the resaults.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but I had this same issue and the difference I saw between NetworkManager and using the CLI is the device type.

NetworkManager uses by default a Tun device and openvpn a Tap device. Changing the option "Set virtual device type" to "TAP" in Advanced OpenVPN properties allowed me to reach the remote LAN.